# ActiveRecord return lazy collection instead of array when calling #all

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

When I do `User.all` it returns an array. Is there a way to return the same type that doing `where` returns, so I can keep filtering the collection?

Comment: If you want to filter, why don't you use ```where```?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using Rails 3, use `#scoped`

http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/NamedScope/ClassMethods/scoped